# NIFI ExecuteScript 1.10.0 Processor : java.io.IOException: Mark invalid

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I use ExecuteScript Processor with python. it used to work ,but today i write a more than two thousand lines of script and the  problem is happended. The log as follow,i think is the **BufferedReader** method mark/reset caused this problem !

```
2020-05-13 17:21:49,433 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-87] o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript ExecuteScript[id=b015d494-32cb-35f7-92b2-268a30ff730b] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:254)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:226)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.compileScript(PyScriptEngine.java:93)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at org.apache.nifi.script.impl.JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.eval(JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.java:62)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:238)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.python.core.PyException: null
    at org.python.core.Py.JavaError(Py.java:552)
    at org.python.core.ParserFacade.fixParseError(ParserFacade.java:107)
    at org.python.core.ParserFacade.parseExpressionOrModule(ParserFacade.java:136)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:320)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:316)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:308)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.compileScript(PyScriptEngine.java:87)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:512)
    at org.python.core.ParserFacade.parseExpressionOrModule(ParserFacade.java:133)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Script example code as follow,i simulate my script,the 'for loop' would have been going on,the original script will reach line 2473

```
import json
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, flowfile):
        self.ff = flowfile
        pass
    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        prop_col_names = ['NOROUTE_FLAG','DIP_TOTALITEM','INPUTDATE','MODEL_ALIAS','LINE_RATE','PWB_NO','WMS_SEND_FLAG','UNIT_PRICE','DIP_CHECK_DATE','LINK_FLAG','PCB_QTY','MODEL_TYPE','MP_FLAG','YHP_APP','ONENESS_QTY','SMT_CAR_QTY','SMT_TOTALITEM','KP_NO','MODEL_VER','PALLET_SNTYPEID','VALID_FLAG','LINE_ROUTE','CHECK_FLAG','REDUCETONORMAL','WUNIT','CHANGE_DATE','PRODUCT_NAME','AUTO_SN','SSN_MODEL','SSN_DEFINE','SMT_TOTALSOLDER','CREATE_DATE','PACK_DATE','PICK_DATE','PCB_QTY_FLAG','GWEIGHT','SB_MODEL','MO_TYPE','QTY_CONTROL_FLAG','SSN_TYPE','PCBA_VER','NWEIGHT','CLASS_NAME','DEFAULT_LINE','MODEL_RANGE2','MODEL_RANGE1','ROUTE_CODE','SAP_MODEL_FLAG','EXTRA_QTY','CATEGORY','POINT_A','POINT_B','PROD_TYPE','START_SN','BOM_NO','MODEL_PARENT','STANDARD','KEYIN_EMPCODE','DIP_TOTALSOLDER','MODEL_ATTRIBUTE','PCB_CODE','PCB_VER','PCB_TYPE_ID','TYPE_NUMBER','BIOS_VER','SERIES_NAME','MFG_PART','CHANGE_EMP','END_SN','NORMALTOADD','PB_FLAG','SP_MODEL_FLAG','SSN_LENGTH','CREATE_EMP','LABEL_CONTROL_FLAG']
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        obj = json.loads(text)

        system_id = self.ff.getAttribute('system_id')
        source_schema = self.ff.getAttribute('source_schema')
        source_table = self.ff.getAttribute('source_table')

        work_master_cap_prop = []
        work_master_cap = []
        m_work_master_cap_s_work_master_cap_prop_by_work_master_cap_prop = []

        for row in obj:
            main_id = row['MODEL_NAME']
            source_schema = row.get('owner', source_schema)
            source_table = row.get('table', source_table)
            op = row.get('op', 'i')
            scn = row.get('scn', -1)
            train_id = row.get('train_id', '')
            train_seq = row.get('train_seq', -1)
            rowid = row.get('rowid', '')
            load_seq = row.get('load_seq', -1)
            row_status = 'I'
            for col_name in prop_col_names:
                d = {}
                m = {}
                if col_name == 'NOROUTE_FLAG':
                    d = {
                        'ACTION_FLAG': op,
                        'TXN_ID': train_id,
                        'TXN_SEQ': train_seq,
                        'ACTION_SEQ': load_seq,
                        'GROUP_KEY': main_id,
                        'Value': row['NOROUTE_FLAG'],
                        'ID': 'NOROUTE_FLAG',
                        'ROW_STATUS': row_status,
                        'GROUP_TABLE': source_schema + '.' + source_table,
                        'R_ID': rowid,
                        'SYSTEM_ID': system_id,
                        'SCN': scn
                        }
                    m = {
                        'ACTION_FLAG': op,
                        'TXN_ID': train_id,
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_SYSTEM_ID': system_id,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_SYSTEM_ID': system_id,
                        'TXN_SEQ': train_seq,
                        'ACTION_SEQ': load_seq,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_ID': row['MODEL_NAME'],
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_ID': 'NOROUTE_FLAG',
                        'ROW_STATUS': row_status,
                        'R_ID': rowid,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_GROUP_KEY': main_id,
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_GROUP_TABLE': source_schema + '.' + source_table,
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_GROUP_KEY': main_id,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_GROUP_TABLE': source_schema + '.' + source_table,
                        'SCN': scn
                        }
                elif col_name == 'DIP_TOTALITEM':
                    d = {
                        'ACTION_FLAG': op,
                        'TXN_ID': train_id,
                        'TXN_SEQ': train_seq,
                        'ACTION_SEQ': load_seq,
                        'GROUP_KEY': main_id,
                        'Value': row['DIP_TOTALITEM'],
                        'ID': 'DIP_TOTALITEM',
                        'ROW_STATUS': row_status,
                        'GROUP_TABLE': source_schema + '.' + source_table,
                        'R_ID': rowid,
                        'SYSTEM_ID': system_id,
                        'SCN': scn
                        }
                    m = {
                        'ACTION_FLAG': op,
                        'TXN_ID': train_id,
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_SYSTEM_ID': system_id,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_SYSTEM_ID': system_id,
                        'TXN_SEQ': train_seq,
                        'ACTION_SEQ': load_seq,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_ID': row['MODEL_NAME'],
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_ID': 'DIP_TOTALITEM',
                        'ROW_STATUS': row_status,
                        'R_ID': rowid,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_GROUP_KEY': main_id,
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_GROUP_TABLE': source_schema + '.' + source_table,
                        'FID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_PROP_GROUP_KEY': main_id,
                        'PID_WORK_MASTER_CAP_GROUP_TABLE': source_schema + '.' + source_table,
                        'SCN': scn
                        }

                work_master_cap_prop.append(d)
                m_work_master_cap_s_work_master_cap_prop_by_work_master_cap_prop.append(m)
            work_master_cap_info = {
                'ACTION_FLAG': op,
                'TXN_ID': train_id,
                'DESCRIPTION': row['MODEL_SERIAL'],
                'TXN_SEQ': train_seq,
                'ACTION_SEQ': load_seq,
                'GROUP_KEY': main_id,
                'ID': row['MODEL_NAME'],
                'ROW_STATUS': row_status,
                'GROUP_TABLE': source_schema + '.' + source_table,
                'R_ID': rowid,
                'SYSTEM_ID': system_id,
                'SCN': scn
            }
            work_master_cap.append(work_master_cap_info)


        data = {
            'work_master_cap_prop': work_master_cap_prop,
            'work_master_cap': work_master_cap,
            'm_work_master_cap_s_work_master_cap_prop_by_work_master_cap_prop': m_work_master_cap_s_work_master_cap_prop_by_work_master_cap_prop
        }
        outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')))


flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback(flowFile))
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

If i want to use a custom processor to handle python script ,Any recommendation?

Comment: This question is not complete to allow other users to help you debug. You will need to share the script code and an example of incoming data that causes it to fail. It is discouraged to write a script that large as well; if you have processing that complex, I recommend putting it in a custom processor.

Comment: i have updated my question. the processor can run sucessfully until  script change to 2000 line , and i try  to simplify my script by reduce the for loop branch,it also can run .@Andy

Comment: If i want to use a custom processor to handle python script ,Any recommendation?@Andy

Comment: I would recommend either writing a custom processor to do the mapping ([presentation about writing custom processors here](https://github.com/alopresto/slides/tree/master/ioth_2019)) or break this process into discrete steps and use the builtin processors, such as `EvaluateJsonPath` and `UpdateAttribute` or `UpdateRecord`. It looks like all you're doing is mapping incoming JSON fields to different keys in the output. If you need more complicated JSON mapping, I would suggest using Jolt.

Comment: @Andy i got the same error before because the script automatically generated is too large.And i have no idea to slove it.Can u get me suggestion?for ex,to split the script into two part,and then flow into the two same ExecuteScript processor.TIA

Comment: The `ExecuteScript` processor is not designed for extensive scripts. I don't know if there is a hard limit at 2000 lines, but that amount of code is too large & complex to be well-suited for the `ExecuteScript` processor. Either decompose the logic into discrete parts and put them into individual components, or write a custom processor which can be as large and complex as you like.

Comment: NiFi is a Java platform. If you have existing Python logic that you don't wish to re-write in Java, put it in an external Python script and call it with `ExecuteStreamCommand`.